# Commutative ring with some special kind of localizations being Noetherian

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. If for every non invertible element $f\in R$, we have $R_f$ (the localization of $R$ at the multiplicative set $\{f^n:n\ge 0\}$ ) is a Noetherian ring, then is $R$ a Noetherian ring ? If this is not true in general, then does assuming some further hypothesis like $R$ is an integral domain or say $R$ is local, would imply $R$ is Noetherian ?

Comment: A silly kind of counterexample: let $F$ be a field, and let $R = F[X_{1}, X_{2}, \cdots], \mathfrak{m} = \langle X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots \rangle$ and put $A = R/\mathfrak{m}^{2}$. Then $A$ is a non-Noetherian local ring with unique maximal ideal $I := \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^{2}$. The noninvertible elements are precisely the elements of $I$; but since every $x \in I$ is nilpotent, $A_{x}$ is the zero ring for any $x \in I$, hence Noetherian.

Comment: @AlexWertheim: Ah right ... creating a non-Noetherian local ring whose every non-unit element is nilpotent does indeed work, very clever, thanks ... do you have an integral domain counter-example though ?

Comment: Happy to help! I'm afraid I don't know any integral domain counter-example. (For me, it is hard to think of a non-Noetherian integral domain whose non-invertible elements are easy to describe, let alone their localizations - but I'm sure someone who knows more commutative algebra than I do will be up to the task.)

Comment: Valuation rings are not in general Noetherian, they are domains and local. If you invert any non-zero non-unit, you get the fraction field.

Comment: @Mohan Is it true that inverting a non-unit in a valuation ring is enough to get its field of fractions? What about a valuation ring $V$ of rank at least two, $\mathfrak p\subsetneq\mathfrak m$ non-zero prime ideals and $a\in\mathfrak m\setminus\mathfrak p$? In this case $V[a^{-1}]\subseteq V_{\mathfrak p}$.

Comment: @Mohan's claim is true if $V$ is a valuation ring of rank one. And there are non-Noetherian valuation rings of rank one.

Comment: As @user26857 mentioned, for rank one valuation rings (which I didn't say), it is true. For a dvr, this is trivial, since inverting any non-unit gives you the fraction field. You do not have to have the element a uniformizer, but just a power of the uniformizer upto unit, which is true for a dvr.